# How to expose plain Apache Kafka topics messages on REST GET method so, it works as API gateway?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've made a REST connector to push NodeJS Service response to Kafka but now I want to write or use a REST sink connector to expose my API response stored as message.I'm able to get Kafka message over websocket, what is standard way to expose other than API Gateway using plain Apache kafka(no third party platform)

works with WebSocket but want to expose as API Gateway or something reliable usign kafka

No third part platform just Apache kafka

Comment: Kafka doesn't have websocket or REST, so you therefore need a third party resource

Comment: Not very clear with your requirement. Why can't the consumer directly access the kafka then ?